# How do I know if violations of assumption of sparsity is problematic?

Tags: bayesian, lasso, regularization, networks, social-network

I am running a network analysis in R using the `estimateNetwork(default = "EBICglasso")` function from the bootnet package. I have set `threshold = TRUE` because a dense network was selected without it.

However I now get this warning:

`Note: Network with lowest lambda selected as best network: assumption of sparsity might be violated.`

Despite this, when I plot the network it is much more interpretable. How do I know if this is a genuine problem or not?

Comment: estimateNetwork is not a base R function, you need to provide more details on the code you’re running.

Comment: Thanks, I added the package name (bootnet).